If I stop gamesharing with one friend on PS5 and start gamesharing with another, can the first friend then buy that game and play it?
I know this is a very confusing question, but my brother and I have been gamesharing for years, and my son just got his own PS5 for Christmas. So I now need to stop gamesharing with my brother so that I can gameshare with my son.
My question is: once I do that, I know my brother will lose access to my games, but can he then go and buy College Football and play it even though it was already downloaded on his console previously?

Yes, he can.
When you lose the access on a digital game you still have the game and the savefiles on your console, but the game just can't be started because of a padlock icon.
Buying the game allows you to actually own the game license, this removes the padlock making the digital content accessible again.
